# Spring mvc parse object using jackson?

Tags: java, spring, jquery, spring-mvc, jackson

My bean class ,

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Information {

    private LinkedList<String> information ;

    public LinkedList<String> getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(LinkedList<String> information) {
        this.information = information;
        System.out.println("List is : "+information);
    }


}
```

My controller ,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registerDn.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Information registerDn( @RequestParam(value = "dn", required = false) String dn,
        @RequestParam(value = "acd", required = false) String acd ){
    System.out.println("DN is : "+dn+   "    acd : "+acd);
    WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
    UserOperation oper = (UserOperation)ctx.getBean("operation");
    oper.registerDn(dn);

    Information info = (Information) ctx.getBean("info");
    return info;
}
```

My jquery will be ,

```
function registerDn(){

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: contexPath + "/registerDn.html",
        data: "dn=" + dn + "&acd=" + acd,  
        success: function(response){

            var userInfo = "<ol>";

            for( i =0 ; i < response.information.length ; i++){
                userInfo += "<br><li><b>Name</b> : " + response.information[i] ;
            }

            userInfo += "</ol>";

            //Used to display the list
            $('#getlist').html(dn + " is : " + userInfo); 

        },  
        error: function(e){  
            alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }, 

    }); 

}
```

I get the Success in the jquery-ajax.But dont know how to parse it and show it in the view.

or How to get the list in the bean class using jquery-ajax when I click a button.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: you have already done the code for view, just change $('#getlist').html(dn + " is : " + response.userInfo);  to $('#getlist').html(dn + " is : " + userInfo);

Comment: @Krisl Shows the `information.length is null or not an object` error in browser ?

Comment: whats the content of response? `{}`?

Comment: @wrm can't understand what you are asking?

Comment: in your ajax callback: what is really returned (i.e. the content of `response`)? (as it seems that it does NOT contain information (or its null))

Comment: var data=eval(response); then use data.information it should work..

Comment: It looks like the issue is in your server code, either you dont have jackson jars in your classpath or  ctx.getBean("info") is returning null. Can you try hard coding the data in information linkedList

Comment: Its better to use firebug in mozilla or chrome developer console to see the request and response so you can easily find the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your sample code that says the response should be / is expected to be a JSON object.

1. Jackson jars have to be on the class path, so that the MappingJackson HttpMessageConverter is configured in your application's context
2. jQuery ajax config should have dataType defined as json or use the `produces` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation and set the value as `application/json`

Basically, if Spring knows that the response content type should be json, it will use Jackson Mapping Converter to convert your pojo to JSON, and then your jQuery success callback will get a JSON object.

You should see exactly what is happening with FireBug though.